# How to combine these circuits?

Tags: circuit-design, design

I'm going to make an Emergency Braking System for my high school project except there is no brakes in the model car for the sake of simplicity, the circuit will just turn the motor off.

[image]

The circuit above is what I will use for the sensors detecting obstacles. And below is a circuit to turn on the car with a switch.

[image]

Now I want that switch to control both the sensor circuit and car motor itself, so all the system will be in sync. And also to have only 1 battery connected to both circuits.

Lastly, I was wondering if I would need a transistor to invert the signal because when the sensor circuit is off I want the motor on, and when the sensor is on the motor should turn off.

Comment: Will it be a "toy" car, or a car with humans on board? I assume toy.

Comment: Yes, small toy car. No humans.

Answer (score 5):

For the moment, I'm going to ignore the details of your sensor circuitry, and just consider what it takes to have an LM 358 drive a motor. Right now, your LM 358 is driving an LED. An LM 358 can typically drive something like 40 mA, and an LED typically draws something like 20 mA, so the LM 358 can drive it directly.

A motor is almost certain to draw more than 40 mA, so an LM 358 won't be able to drive it directly. A motor will also "kick back" a fairly substantial voltage pulse when you turn it off, so you need a little bit of protection (usually a diode) to keep that from burning things up.

At its simplest, that leads to a circuit something along this general line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzAfF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown the driver as a FET, but you can also use a BJT. The main thing is that it needs to be rated for the current your motor will draw (and if that's very much, it may need to be mounted on a heat sink).

The basic idea here is pretty simple: the LM 358 output drives a voltage on the gate of the FET. The FET basically acts like a switch: voltage on the gate opens and closes the switch, so current can flow from source to drain. That's in series with the motor, so the motor can only run when the "switch" is closed.

When the "switch" opens, and the motor kicks out a pulse, the diode conducts it directly to ground, without going through the transistor, so it won't burn up the transistor.

Oh, I almost forgot one other thing: if you want to have your emergency brake act more like a brake, you can do a little more: you can put a transistor in parallel with the motor, and drive it with the opposite logic: that is, "close" that switch when you want to stop the car.

When there's no power supplied to the motor, but the car is still moving, the motor will act as a generator. If you put a transistor in parallel with it, closing that "switch" will put a load on the generator, which in turn puts a load on the wheels.

Although they use the load to recharge the batteries instead of just dissipating it as heat, this is the basic idea of the regenerative braking in real electric cars.

Doing this well can be a little trick though: you generally want a little time delay, to be sure this transistor is only conducting after the other one turns off (and this one turns off before the other one turns on).

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate your protection diode placement. Or perhaps change it to a zener as currently placed. As is, the diode cannot conduct current to ground.

Comment: @Marla: oops--yes, it should have been a Zener.

Comment: I have a standard 3V 1.5A DC motor. How big of a resistor do I need in the circuit you made? Also if I use a 9V battery, would I need a resistor in series with the motor?

Comment: @dzaky: The resistor in the circuit isn't critical--something like 1K or so. Fortunately, the LM 358 can also run off of 3V. But no, you don't want to use a resistor to drop the voltage--for running off of batteries, you probably want a switch mode power supply. But if you're thinking of a normal 9V battery...that's not going to give you anywhere close to 1.5 amps. A battery that can safely output 1.5 amps is going to be considerably larger than that.